# Add a new field to documents in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I have an index in ES with documents in the format below

```
   "_id": "9hGu8IwBXomVfLb-UJJo",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "host": {
        "memory": {
          "availableSwap": 7040704,
          "used": 229712,
          "total": 4042716,
          "shared": 263628,
          "free": 7270416,
          "totalSwap": 7074752,
          "cached": 1196976
        }
      },
      "@timestamp": "2024-01-10T00:03:24.798128615Z",
      "**sysUpTime**": 141314970
```

I need to add a new field to calculate the availability% using this formula;  availability={sysUpTimeT1-sysUpTimeT0}/300

I'm newbie to Elasticsearch and I need help to acheive this please.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to index the new value and just have a new field at search time, you can try [Runtime Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html)

If you need to index availability you can use the [processor and create your script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-processor.html) that will calculate the value for the new field and use the reindex API to apply the operation.

Another option is to [create a script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/create-stored-script-api.html) and use the [update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#update-api-example) to update the documents.

Remember to [update the mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) with the new field before creating it.